# How to make the following vertical line and two lines of equation inside of bracket

Tags: equations, brackets

How to reproduce this one? [image]

I am mostly concerned with the vertical bar and getting two lines of equations behind it.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  This depends on the code for the rest of the display, e.g. if you have used `\left\langle...\right\rangle` then `\middle\vert` is what you want, perhaps with extra space around it.

Comment: @AndrewSwann never knew of `\middle` up till now.

Comment: @Skllmon `\middle` was introduced in `etex`, which is now standard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick way using `\left ... \right` pairs and `array` (and thanks to [@AndrewSwann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/465980/how-to-make-the-following-vertical-line-and-two-lines-of-equation-inside-of-brac/465983#comment1171129_465980) a `\middle`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  B = \left\langle \sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_{n-1} \middle\vert\,
  \begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    \sigma_i \sigma_j = \sigma_j \sigma_i,
      & \lvert i - j \rvert > 1 \\
    \sigma_i \sigma_j \sigma_i = \sigma_j \sigma_i \sigma_j,
      & \lvert i - j \rvert = 1
  \end{array}
  \right\rangle
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! seems like I have to look into `array`. Thanks so much

Comment: @Marsl `array` is just like `tabular` but for maths.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\middle\vert` for the rule, and `alignedat` for the conditions:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  B_{n} =  \left\langle \sigma_{1},\dots,\sigma_{n-1} \;\middle\vert\;
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
      \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j} &=\sigma_{j}\sigma_{i},&\ &\lvert i-j \rvert
      > 1,\\
      \sigma_{i}\sigma_{j}\sigma_{i} &=
      \sigma_{j}\sigma_{i}\sigma_{j},&&
      \lvert i-j \rvert = 1
    \end{alignedat}
  \right\rangle
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The OP seems also to want a brace like for `cases`; I'd not align the equals signs, because they're not related to each other. So `cases` instead of `aligned` should do.

Comment: @egreg I see no brace.  I was reproducing the OPs alignment. It is not the way I would phrase such a thing myself.